# ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor -- in windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I had downloaded `oracle` 12c in my `windows` 10 laptop and completed all configurations as asked. While connecting `sql plus` through cmd, i am getting above error. Also checked the running services but didn't help.

Can anyone let me how to connect? or whats the problem.

**CMD log :**

```
C:\Users\jinda>sqlplus sys/Oracle_1@pdborcl as sysdba;

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Oct 9 21:14:23 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor


Enter user-name:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name: lsnrctl services
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus

C:\Users\jinda>lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 09-OCT-2017 21:16:54

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522)))
Services Summary...
Service "1aebfa0274e749d5b9becde74103f248" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:8 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: DESKTOP-N4NI40G, pid: 3592>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-N4NI40G)(PORT=58940))
Service "pdborcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully

C:\Users\jinda>
```